# How to specify an arbitrary slope with the vector command?

Tags: diagrams

i want to draw a vector with the `vector` command, but it seems like that the slope must be specified in integers less than some limit, thus commands like

```
\put(0,10){\vector(8,7){200}}
```

will failed to compile, but this works:

```
\put(0,10){\vector(1,0){200}}
```

so how can i specify arbitrary slope, is there a way to specify two endpoints rather than specifying the slope

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This specific limitation is removed by the [pict2e](http://ctan.org/pkg/pict2e) package (load the package and it should "just work"). However, for programmatic drawing in LaTeX these days I'd suggest looking into [PGF/Tikz](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/latex/ltx-341.html, the `\vector` command takes only integers -5 < x, y < 5.